# Lagrangian manifolds: basic standard theory

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, manifolds, book-recommendation, quadrics

It is the first time that I start to learn about Lagrangian manifolds so I would like some suggestion about book and article to read. Due to the fact that is the first time, I need a book with the principal results with no complicated explanation. Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: Is this related to "lagrangian eigenmaps"?

Comment: what do you mean with this term "lagrangian eigenmaps"

Comment: Oops sorry, it was laplacian eigenmaps. I was being confused.

Comment: no but i'm not expert in this argument

Comment: By Lagrangian manifold do you mean the one described in here:https://math.berkeley.edu/~giventh/papers/sing_lag_var.pdf ?

Comment: yes. I would like to study that manifolds. For example one of the question that i would like to answer what are the connected components of a lagrangian manifolds?

Comment: Ok. It is more commonly called Lagrangian submanifold as it is defined as a submanifold of a symplectic manifold. To know more about that, you have to know symplectic manifold and there's a book called "Lectures on symplectic geometry" (http://www.math.ist.utl.pt/~acannas/Books/lsg.pdf) which is quite elementary.